# Is there a way to make these two objects seamless?

Tags: materials

The colors of the bricks slightly don't line up, and I want the buildings to be modular, as I need to make a lot of them, is there any way to fix this?

(they use the same material btw)

[image]

Edit: I solved the problem! For anyone who also has this problem, the answer I came up with was to warp the main face texture horizontally  so every other grout lines up with the edge of the object, then flip the copy 180 degrees on the Z axis.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! For anyone who also has this problem, the answer I came up with was to warp the main face texture horizontally so every other grout lines up with the edge of the object, then flip the copy 180 degrees on the Z axis.